# How to set the charset when using Pandas to_html?

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, export

I am using Pandas [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method to generate HTML output, but I need to set the `charset` of generated document to `'utf-8'`, like:

```
<meta charset='utf-8' >
```

Any Idea how may I do that?

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`'<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>' +  df.to_html()`

Comment: to_html write to file, it does not return the html output.

Comment: It returns a string when no file name is provided, but you can add <head><meta... in file as well, read it, add the lines and write again?